# Editing my CV from a template

Tags: pdftex, cv

I am creating a CV in latex using a template and now I want some help redesigning my CV, I paste the code here:

Firstly I want the word "Curriculum Vitae" in bold and larger text size maybe in a black colored box in white font. There is some personal data so I wiped it out and I attached the outcome of this code here.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cfr-lm}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\setlength{\multicolsep}{0pt} 
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\geometry{left=0.6cm, top=0.5cm, right=0.6cm, bottom=0.5cm}
% Adjust margins
%\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.5in}
%\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-0.5in}
%\addtolength{\textwidth}{1in}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{
    frame code={}
    center title,
    left=0pt,
    right=0pt,
    top=0pt,
    bottom=0pt,
    colback=gray!20,
    colframe=white,
    width=\dimexpr\textwidth\relax,
    enlarge left by=-2mm,
    boxsep=4pt,
    arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,
}

\urlstyle{same}

\raggedright
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}

% Sections formatting
\titleformat{\section}{
  \vspace{-4pt}\scshape\raggedright\large
}{}{0em}{}[\color{black}\titlerule \vspace{-7pt}]

%-------------------------
% Custom commands
\newcommand{\resumeItem}[2]{
  \item{
    \textbf{#1}{:\hspace{0.5mm}#2 \vspace{-0.5mm}}
  }
}

\newcommand{\resumePOR}[3]{
\vspace{0.5mm}\item
    \begin{tabular*}{0.97\textwidth}[t]{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
        \textbf{#1.}\hspace{0.3mm}#2 & \textit{\small{#3}} 
    \end{tabular*}
    \vspace{-2mm}
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubheading}[4]{
\vspace{0.5mm}\item
    \begin{tabular*}{0.98\textwidth}[t]{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
        \textbf{#1} & \textit{\footnotesize{#4}} \\
        \textit{\footnotesize{#3}} &  \footnotesize{#2}\\
    \end{tabular*}
    \vspace{-2.4mm}
}

\newcommand{\resumeProject}[4]{
\vspace{0.5mm}\item
    \begin{tabular*}{0.98\textwidth}[t]{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
        \textbf{#1} & \textit{\footnotesize{#3}} \\
        \footnotesize{\textit{#2}} & \footnotesize{#4}
    \end{tabular*}
    \vspace{-2.4mm}
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubItem}[2]{\resumeItem{#1}{#2}\vspace{-4pt}}

% \renewcommand{\labelitemii}{$\circ$}
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\vcenter{\hbox{\tiny$\bullet$}}$}

\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListStart}{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*,labelsep=0mm]}
\newcommand{\resumeHeadingSkillStart}{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*,itemsep=1.7mm, rightmargin=2ex]}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListStart}{\begin{justify}\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=3ex, rightmargin=2ex, noitemsep,labelsep=1.2mm,itemsep=0mm]\small}

\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListEnd}{\end{itemize}\vspace{2mm}}
\newcommand{\resumeHeadingSkillEnd}{\end{itemize}\vspace{-2mm}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListEnd}{\end{itemize}\end{justify}\vspace{-2mm}}
\newcommand{\cvsection}[1]{%
\vspace{2mm}
\begin{tcolorbox}
    \textbf{\large #1}
\end{tcolorbox}
    \vspace{-4mm}
}

\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}%
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}%
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}%


\newcommand{\name}{Ripan Das} % Your Name
\newcommand{\course}{Master of Science} % Your Course
\newcommand{\roll}{Your Roll No} % Your Roll No.
\newcommand{\phone}{xxxxxxxxx} % Your Phone Number
\newcommand{\emaila}{xxxxxxxx} %Email 1
\newcommand{\emailb}{xxxxxxxxxxx} %Email 2
\newcommand{\github}{your GitHub link} %Github
%\newcommand{\website}{https://www.yourwebsite.com} %Website
\newcommand{\linkedin}{your linkedIn link} %linkedin




\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\textbf{Curriculum Vitae}
\end{center}
\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont

%----------HEADING-----------------
\parbox{2.35cm}{%

}\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2.8cm\relax}{
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{L r}
  \textbf{\LARGE \name} & +91-\phone\\
  Date of Birth: xxxx &  +91-xxxxxxxx\\
  Age:xxx &  \href{mailto:\emailb}{\emaila}\\
   {\course, Mathematics} &\href{mailto:\emailb}{\emailb} \\
  {xxxxxxxxxxx} 
\end{tabularx}
}

\vspace{-2mm}
%-------------SUMMARY-----------------
\iffalse
\section{\textbf{Summary}}
This CV is automatically generated and deployed using the \href{https://github.com/kryptoniteX/autocvmkr}{autoCVmkr} template along with GitHub Actions such that a new version of the CV is compiled, published and ready for use when the cv.tex file is updated.
\fi
%-----------EDUCATION-----------------
\section{\textbf{Education}}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5pt} % Default value: 6pt
% \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1} % Default value: 1
\small{\begin{tabularx}
{\dimexpr\textwidth-2mm\relax}{|c|C|c|c|}
  \hline
  \textbf{Year} & \textbf{Degree/Certificate} & \textbf{Institute} & \textbf{CGPA/Percentage} \\
  \hline
  2020-2023 & B.Sc. Mathematics & xxxx & xxxxx\\
 
  \hline
  2020 & xxxx & xxxxx, Kolkata & xxx\% \\
  \hline
  2018 & xxxx & Sxxxxx, Kolkata & xxxx\% \\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}}
\vspace{-1mm}

%-----------About me-----------------
\section{\textbf{About me}}
I'm Ripan Das, currently pursuing MSc in Mathematics at xxxxxx. I completed my BSc at the same university with CGPA xxxx. I mainly interested in Pure  mathematics and I have got the basics down from regular textbooks of Group theory, Ring theory, Field, and Module theory, Linear algebra, Real analysis, Topology and Metric space etc. but now I am curious about commutative algebra. I want to figure out how to turn problems from different areas of Mathematics into algebraic ones using certain tricks. I think once I get a grasp on commutative algebra, I will be able to dive into Algebraic topology, Vector bundles, Algebraic geometry, Algebraic number theory, and much more. My research interest includes Commutative algebra and Algebraic geometry mainly.     
  
      
\vspace{-2.5mm}
%-----------PROJECTS-----------------
\section{\textbf{Projects, Camps and Seminar}}
\resumeSubHeadingListStart
    
    \resumeProject
      {Axxxxxx-I, 2023} %Project Name
      {Mathematics,xxxx} %Project Name, Location Name
      {xxxx} %Event Dates
      
      \resumeItemListStart
        \item {The xxxxx are aimed at first and second-year Ph.D. students. This year AFS-I is organised by xxxxx. As I pursue my M.Sc, I applied for xxxxx and I was selected and my id is xxxx1.}
      \resumeItemListEnd
    
     \vspace{-1mm}
     
     \resumeProject
      {xxxx} %Project Name
      {Mathematics, xxxx} %Project Name, Location Name
      {xxx} %Event Dates
      
      \resumeItemListStart
        \item xxx is aimed to bring researchers and professionals to discuss recent developments in Pure and Applied mathematics and their applications in Mathematical Modeling, in order to create a professional knowledge exchange platform between mathematicians.}
      \resumeItemListEnd
    
     \vspace{-1mm}
     
    \resumeProject
      {xxx, 2022} %Project Name
      {Mathematics,xxx} %Project Name, Location Name
      {xxxx} %Event Dates
      
      \resumeItemListStart
        \item {The primary purpose of xxxx is to emphasize the importance of learning mathematics by doing it, with a focus on solving problems, understanding key examples that underlie and elucidate fundamental principles, and real-world applications. }
      \resumeItemListEnd
    
   
      
\resumeSubHeadingListEnd
\vspace{-7.5mm}

\section{\textbf{Technical Skills}}
 \resumeHeadingSkillStart
  \resumeSubItem{Programming Languages} % Category
    { \LaTeX, Matlab, HTML.}
    
    %\vspace{-0.5mm}
    
    
 \resumeSubItem{Operating Systems} % Category
    {Windows, Linux \& Android.} \ % Skills
    
    %\vspace{-0.5mm}
    
 
 \resumeHeadingSkillEnd

\vspace{-1.5mm}

\section{\textbf{Key courses taken}}
\resumeHeadingSkillStart
 \resumeSubItem{Mathematics} % Category
    {I am mainly interested in pure mathematics in which I learned basic Real analysis, Topology, Metric space, Complex analysis, Linear algebra, Group theory, Ring, and Field theory as well as Module theory, Elementary Number theory, Measure theory, and Function of several variables.}
    %\vspace{-0.5mm}
 \resumeSubItem{Others}
 {I also learned C/C++, DSA, Combinatorics, Numerical analysis, Partial differential equations, and Ordinary differential equations, Graph theory.}
%  \resumeSubItem{Electrical and Electronics} % Category
%     {Advanced Control Systems, Digital Systems, Microprocessors} % Skills
\resumeHeadingSkillEnd

\vspace{-1mm}
%---------------CERTIFICATIONS-------------------
\section{\textbf{Certifications}}
    \resumeItemListStart
        \item {\href{paste link here}{\textbf{B.Sc degree}}}
        {xxxxx} %Certifying Authority
        \item {\href{paste link here}{\textbf{xxxx}}}
        {xxxx } %Certifying Authority
        \item {\href{paste link here}{\textbf{xxx}}}
        {xxxx8} %Certifying Authority
        \item {\href{paste link here}{\textbf{Jxxxx}}}
        {xxx} %Certifying Authority
    \resumeItemListEnd
\vspace{-4mm}



\section{\textbf{Miscellaneous}}
\vspace{-0.1mm}
\resumeSubHeadingListStart
\resumePOR{Achievement 1} % Award
    { xxxxx} % Event
    {2020} %Event Year
    
   % \resumePOR{Achievement 1} % Award
    %{ xxxxx} % Event
   % {2020} %Event Year
\vspace{-0.1mm}
\resumeSubHeadingListEnd
%-------------------------------------------
\vfill
\center{\footnotesize Last updated: \today}

\end{document}
```

Please help. [image: If possible please put "curriculum vitae" in the black colored box with white big font.]

Edit: I am able to edit my code. Here is the following

```
\begin{center}
\fcolorbox{white}{black}{\huge \textcolor{white}{\textbf{Curriculum Vitae}}}
\end{center}
```

Now the problem is that the box is small. How to increase its size?